# Stitching panorama on iOS crashes with cvflann::anyimpl::bad_any_cast

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, casting

I have no experience with c++ but i need to interface with OpenCV in an iOS app. I have it building correctly but it crashes when calling some c++ code.

The code below crashes with this message: `libc++abi.dylib: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cvflann::anyimpl::bad_any_cast
terminating with uncaught exception of type cvflann::anyimpl::bad_any_cast`

```
bool stitch(const std::vector <cv::Mat> & images, cv::Mat &result) {
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(false);

    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(images, result); <-- Crash!

    if (status != Stitcher::OK) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I assume this is because the input or output to `stitch(...)` is an incorrect type but i cannot figure out what i need to give it or how to convert it.

The function I'm calling is defined as such:

```
Status stitch(InputArrayOfArrays images, OutputArray pano);
```

Where `InputArrayOfArrays` and `OutputArray` are all aliases of [_InputArray](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L146)

What to do?

Edit: This is using OpenCV 3.0 where i think the example code I'm using was for OpenCV 2.4. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Switching back to OpenCV 2.4 "fixed" the issue however i'd still like to try it with 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

This has been a bug going on in openCV for a while, where it crashes outputting this error in Debug mode only. Try to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme and change the build configuration of "Run" from Debug to Release.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the similar issue happening in IOS related to imports, adding

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

caused bunch of linker warnings and eventually every call to any opencv function failed with the above error, the problem disappeared after I replaced above import with more specific one:

```
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
```

I think that the problem might be related to either import ordering or import duplication, take care hope it helps...

Comment: This fixed it for me. I also had to `#import <opencv2/stitching.hpp>`.

Comment: Generally speaking, try importing one header at a time, starting with the one you know you need - `#import <opencv2/stitching.hpp>` in this case. Compile and find what else you're missing - stitching will need `#import <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>`, but others may require more as well. Eventually you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the include of opencv.hpp in favor of the minimal set of includes worked for me as well.  Here are the includes I ended up with in my case.

```
#import <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#import <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#import <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

I was getting the bad_any_cast from somewhere within a call to FlannBasedMatcher::knnMatch at the time and had tried many "corrections" before finding this solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Same crash Fixed to use below code:

Use open cv 2.4.9 version of stitching for iOS app. Also, use this code it will work great for iOS App

https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch

I already spend too much time to fixed the crash but now it got fixed.